# How to stop activity indicator when the webView loaded the page?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to stop an activity indicator when the `UIWebView` loads the page. I used the `webViewDidFinishLoad` function. But I'm afraid it isn't executed. Where do I need to call the function?

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    actIndicator.stopAnimating()
    print("stopped")
}
```

Comment: http://tuhocswift.com/lap-trinh-swift-can-ban/lap-trinh-swift-activity-indicator-webview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the function itself - it is part of the [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad:) protocol.

What you *must* do is set the delegate of the webview, e.g. with

```
myWebView.delegate = self
```

(assuming you implemented `webViewDidFinishLoad` in the view controller).

Answer (score 1):

You also need to implement

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError)
```

for the cases where something went wrong.